# Scope function defined in link not fired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I made a directive that display a list with an 'add' button. That table is represented twice in the same page but with different forms and table-data:

```
<list ng-model="list1" form-name="form1"></list>
<list ng-model="list2" form-name="form2"></list>
```

In the link function, I define an 'add' function that will use the form and the model specified in the directive declaration:

```
scope: {
  list: '=ngModel',
  formName: '@',
},
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

  scope.add = function() {
    FormService.show(formName).then(function(item) {
      list.push(item);
    });
  }

  var addButton = angular.element('<a ng-click="add()">ADD ITEM</a>');
  var container = angular.element('<div></div>');
  container.append($compile(addButton)(scope));
  element.replaceWith(container);
```

The problem is that the add function never get called by the 'ADD ITEM' link...

** I cannot use the template configuration object because I need the template to by dynamic

Comment: one thing,  your markup is not correct, you have a div closing an anchor

Comment: typo, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically build your template by providing a function that returns a string to the template property of your directive:

```
scope: {
  list: '=ngModel',
  formName: '@',
},
template: function(element, attrs) {
    var addButton = angular.element('<a ng-click="add()">ADD ITEM</a>');
    var container = angular.element('<div></div>');
    container.append(addButton);
    var str = container.prop('outerHTML');
    return str;
},
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {    
  scope.add = function() {
    FormService.show(formName).then(function(item) {
      list.push(item);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
element.append('<a ng-click="add()">ADD ITEM</a>');
$compile(element.contents())(scope)
```